# Why are MDI child windows non-existent after WM_NCCREATE?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing an MDI graphics app using OpenGL. I have a class `ControllerGL`, based on class `Controller`, which will have the methods (some of which will require their own threads) for drawing to the MDI children. When creating the child windows I set `cbWndExtra` of `WNDCLASSEX` to `sizeof(Win::Controller*)` and retrieve the pointer to the `ControllerGL` class in `WM_NCCREACTE` of the child window procedure using `Set/GetWindowLongPtr()`.

I have this working for a SDI, so I'm quite certain that all the code for setting/retrieving the pointer to the `ControllerGL` class is fine, and in the MDI app the main window is displayed and I get a functioning instance of the `ControllerGL` class from the `WM_NCCREATE` function of the MDI child window procedure.

Menu and string table in resource.rc file:

```
IDM_MDI MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&New",                        ID_FILE_NEW
    END
    POPUP "&Window",
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Cascade",                    ID_WINDOW_CASCADE
        MENUITEM "Tile &Horizontal",            ID_WINDOW_TILEHORIZONTAL
        MENUITEM "Tile &Vertical",              ID_WINDOW_TILEVERTICAL
        MENUITEM "Arrange &Icons",              ID_WINDOW_ARRANGEICONS
    END
END

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_MDI_TITLE           "Win32 MDI"
    IDS_MDI_CLASSNAME       "MDIMAIN"
    IDS_MDICHILD_TITLE      "MDIChild"
    IDS_MDICHILD_CLASSNAME  "MDICHILD"
END
```

This is for the resource.h file

```
#define IDI_MDI                         101
#define IDI_MDI_SMALL                   102
#define IDI_MDICHILD                    103
#define IDI_MDICHILD_SMALL              104
#define IDS_MDI_TITLE                   105
#define IDS_MDI_CLASSNAME               106
#define IDS_MDICHILD_TITLE              107
#define IDS_MDICHILD_CLASSNAME          108
#define IDM_MDI                         109
#define ID_FILE_NEW                     110
#define ID_WINDOW_CASCADE               111
#define ID_WINDOW_TILEHORIZONTAL        112
#define ID_WINDOW_TILEVERTICAL          113
#define ID_WINDOW_ARRANGEICONS          114
#define IDC_MDICHILD_FIRST              50000
```

ViewGL and ModelGL classes for the ControllerGL class:

```
namespace Win
{
    class ViewGL
    {
    public:
        ViewGL();
        ~ViewGL();
    };
}

class ModelGL
{
public:
    ModelGL();
    ~ModelGL();
};
```

The Controller class:

```
#include <windows.h>
namespace Win
{
    class Controller
    {
    public:
        Controller();
        virtual ~Controller ();

        void setHandle(HWND handle);

        virtual int close();
        virtual int create();
        virtual int destroy();
    protected:
        HWND handle;
    };
    inline void Controller::setHandle(HWND hWnd) { handle = hWnd; }
    inline int Controller::close() { ::DestroyWindow(handle); return 0; }
    inline int Controller::create() { return 0; }
    inline int Controller::destroy() { return 0; }
}
```

The ControllerGL class

```
#include "Controller.h"
#include "ViewGL.h"
#include "ModelGL.h"
namespace Win
{
    class ControllerGL : public Controller
    {
    public:
        ControllerGL(ModelGL* model, ViewGL* view);
        ~ControllerGL() {};
    private:
        ModelGL* modelGL;
        ViewGL* viewGL;
    };
}
```

procedure.h

```
#include <windows.h>

namespace Win
{
    LRESULT CALLBACK MDIChildWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
}
```

procedure.cpp

```
#include "procedure.h"
#include "Controller.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK Win::MDIChildWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT returnValue = 0;

    Controller *ctrl;
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)(lParam);
        MDICREATESTRUCT* pMdiCreate = (MDICREATESTRUCT*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
        ctrl = (Controller*)pMdiCreate->lParam;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(ctrl));

        ctrl->setHandle(hWnd);

        SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
    else
        ctrl = reinterpret_cast<Controller *>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0));

    if (!ctrl)
        return DefMDIChildProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            //returnValue = ctrl->create(); For when ControllerGL works properly
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            //returnValue = ctrl->close();
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            //returnValue = ctrl->destroy();
            break;
    }
    //return returnvalue;
    return DefMDIChildProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "ControllerGL.h"
#include "ModelGL.h"
#include "ViewGL.h"
#include "procedure.h"

#include "resource.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

char g_szMDIChild_Title[MAX_LOADSTRING];
char g_szMDIChild_ClassName[MAX_LOADSTRING];

static HINSTANCE g_hInst;
static HWND g_hMDI;
static HWND g_hMDIClient;

static LRESULT CALLBACK MDIWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            DragAcceptFiles(hWnd, TRUE);

            CLIENTCREATESTRUCT ccs;

            ccs.hWindowMenu = GetSubMenu(GetMenu(hWnd), 1);
            ccs.idFirstChild = IDC_MDICHILD_FIRST;

            g_hMDIClient = CreateWindowEx(0,
                "mdiclient",
                NULL,
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                hWnd,
                0,
                g_hInst,
                (void*)(&ccs));

            if (!g_hMDIClient)
                MessageBox(hWnd, "Could not create MDI client!", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

            return 0;
        }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch LOWORD(wParam)
            {
                case ID_FILE_NEW:
                {
                    ModelGL model;
                    Win::ViewGL view;

                    Win::ControllerGL glCtrl(&model, &view);

                    HWND hChild = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_MDICHILD,
                        g_szMDIChild_ClassName,
                        g_szMDIChild_Title,
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        g_hMDIClient,
                        NULL,
                        g_hInst,
                        (LPVOID)&glCtrl);
                }
                break;
                case ID_WINDOW_CASCADE:
                    PostMessage(g_hMDIClient, WM_MDICASCADE, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_WINDOW_TILEHORIZONTAL:
                    PostMessage(g_hMDIClient, WM_MDITILE, MDITILE_HORIZONTAL, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_WINDOW_TILEVERTICAL:
                    PostMessage(g_hMDIClient, WM_MDITILE, MDITILE_VERTICAL, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_WINDOW_ARRANGEICONS:
                    PostMessage(g_hMDIClient, WM_MDIICONARRANGE, 0, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                {
                    if (LOWORD(wParam) >= IDC_MDICHILD_FIRST)
                    {
                        DefFrameProc(hWnd, g_hMDIClient, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HWND hChild;
                        hChild = (HWND)SendMessage(g_hMDIClient, WM_MDIGETACTIVE, 0, 0);
                        if (hChild)
                        {
                            SendMessage(hChild, WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        break;
        default:
            return DefFrameProc(hWnd, g_hMDIClient, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInst);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    char g_szMDI_Title[MAX_LOADSTRING];
    char g_szMDI_ClassName[MAX_LOADSTRING];

    LoadString(hInst, IDS_MDI_TITLE, g_szMDI_Title, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInst, IDS_MDI_CLASSNAME, g_szMDI_ClassName, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInst, IDS_MDICHILD_TITLE, g_szMDIChild_Title, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInst, IDS_MDICHILD_CLASSNAME, g_szMDIChild_ClassName, MAX_LOADSTRING);

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MDI));

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = Win::MDIChildWndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = sizeof(Win::Controller*);
    wcex.hInstance = hInst;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MDICHILD));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wcex.lpszClassName = g_szMDIChild_ClassName;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MDICHILD_SMALL));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Failed to create MDI child window class", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = MDIWndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInst;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MDI));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_MDI);
    wcex.lpszClassName = g_szMDI_ClassName;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MDI_SMALL));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Failed to create MDI main window class", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    g_hMDI = CreateWindowEx(0,
        g_szMDI_ClassName,
        g_szMDI_Title,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        hInst,
        NULL);

    if (g_hMDI == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create MDI main window!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    g_hInst = hInst;

    MSG uMsg;

    while (GetMessage(&uMsg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        if (!TranslateMDISysAccel(g_hMDIClient, &uMsg) &&
            !TranslateAccelerator(uMsg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &uMsg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&uMsg);
            DispatchMessage(&uMsg);
        }
    };

    return (int)uMsg.wParam;
}
```

When opening a new document with FILE>NEW:

1. None of the child windows are visible.
2. Only the first child window gets an entry in the Windows menu of the main form, and creation of any more windows deletes this entry.
3. I get no errors and attaching a debugger doesn't reveal anything.

Has anybody come across this issue?

Or is it not an issue but a Columbus egg and I'm missing something obvious?

Sorry for the reams of code. I did try to trim it, honest.

Comment: You did not show any of the code that registers the classes, or creates the parent window, or creates the child windows. Please provide a [mcve]. And not related, but `ctrl` does not need to be `static` in `MDIChildWndProc()`.

Comment: Too soon, you can't get the MDICREATESTRUCT* until you get the WM_MDICREATE message.

Comment: Remy Lebeau Minimal sample is large enough for me to get whinged at for it, I'm sure, but there it is. Thankyou.

Comment: @HansPassant `WM_MDICREATE` is sent by the app to the MDI client window, not sent by the OS to the child window. But `WM_MDICREATE` is not being used in this code at all, so there is no `MDICREATESTRUCT`available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least 2 major bugs in your code that you need to fix:

1. `WM_MDICREATE` is a message that is sent by the app to the MDI client window to create an MDI child window. The child WndProc will receive `WM_(NC)CREATE` messages containing the `MDICREATESTRUCT*` pointer that was passed in the `lParam` of `WM_MDICREATE` (if you use `CreateMDIWindow()` instead of `WM_MDICREATE`, it will create the necessary `MDICREATESTRUCT` for you). However, your code is not using `WM_MDICREATE` (or `CreateMDIWindow()`) to create its MDI child windows, you are using `CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_MDICHILD, ...)` directly, and you are not passing a `MDICREATESTRUCT*` in the `lpParam` parameter, you are passing the `ControllerGL*` pointer instead. As such, in your child WndProc's `WM_(NC)CREATE` handler, the `CREATESTRUCT::lpCreateParam`  field will be the `ControllerGL*` pointer, not an `MDICREATESTRUCT*` pointer.
2. your `ID_FILE_NEW` handler is passing a pointer to `CreateWindowEx()` to a local `ControllerGL` object that goes out of scope and is destroyed after `CreateWindowEx()` exits, leaving the newly created MDI child window with a dangling `Controller*` pointer to invalid memory for all subsequent messages. You need to dynamically allocate the `ControllerGL` object via `new` and then `delete` it when the MDI child window is destroyed, such as in its `WM_(NC)DESTROY` handler.

Comment: My understanding is that CreateWindowEx sends a pointer to a MDICREATESTRUCT when the wndExStyle is set to WS_EX_MDICHILD. I did try using SENDMESSAGE with a pointer to a MDICREATESTRUCT, and CreateMDIWindow, and they all work well until I try NC_CREATE in the window procedure. As for your second point; yes, I'm an idiot. Any suggestions for a more elegant way of doing that other than just making the ControllerGL class global?

Comment: This is terribly rude of me but I didn't thank you for your time, so thankyou very much.

Comment: 1) `MDICREATESTRUCT` is sent to `WM_(NC)CREATE` only when a `MDICREATESTRUCT` is given to `CreateWindow/Ex()`. Using `WM_MDICREATE` or `CreateMDIWindow()` handles that internally for you. Your `CreateWindowEx()` code does not do that. Since `WS_EX_MDICHILD` is poorly documented and rarely used in practice, I suggest you use `WM_MDICREATE` or `CreateMDIWindow()` instead. If you are still having trouble when using them, update your question to show that code; 2) use `new` and `delete` to create/destroy the `ControllerGL` object dynamically. You can still store the pointer in the `HWND`.

Comment: The CreateWindowEx, WM_MDICreate and CreateMDIWindow methods all work, as they should do. The only reason I'm sticking with CreateWindowEx is because I read a tutorial online sometime ago which mentioned multithreading mdi child windows, saying that this is not possible(?) using WM_MDICREATE, but now I look for it I can't find it, or remember who or what it was.

Comment: @BenWeston you are not creating your MDI child windows in a worker thread, so choosing to use `CreateWindowEx()` over `WM_MDICHILD`/`CreateMDIWindow()` is a moot point. In any case, see [Using the Multiple Document Interface: Creating a Child Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-the-multiple-document-interface#creating-a-child-window) on MSDN. A worker thread can use `CreateMDIWindow()` instead of `CreateWindowEx()`.  It is only `WM_MDICHILD` that cannot be used across thread boundaries.

Comment: Now the ControllerGL class (which has a thread running a loop to draw to the window) and MDI child windows working as they should, I don't need to run each MDI child window in it's own thread, so I've swapped CreateWindowEx for WM_MDICreate, on your recomendation. Thanks a lot for the pointers (Haha!) and the link. It had to be the MSDN site didn't it: why am I such an idiot?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is humiliating. I had the ControllerGL class declared locally and destroyed when CreateWindowEx() exits, leaving the MDI child window with a pointer to a non-existent instance of the ControllerGL class. I should have done this; create a pointer to the ModelGL, ViewGL and ControllerGL classes at the beginning of the main function:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "ControllerGL.h"
#include "ModelGL.h"
#include "ViewGL.h"
#include "procedure.h"

#include "resource.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

char g_szMDIChild_Title[MAX_LOADSTRING];
char g_szMDIChild_ClassName[MAX_LOADSTRING];

static HINSTANCE g_hInst;
static HWND g_hMDI;
static HWND g_hMDIClient;

ModelGL *model;
Win::ViewGL *view;
Win::ControllerGL *glCtrl;
//The rest of the main function remains unchanged
```

and declare a new instance of each in the ID_FILE_NEW handler, not forgetting to knock off the ampersand from the variable glCtrl, already declared as a pointer:

```
model = new ModelGL();
view = new Win::ViewGL();
glCtrl = new Win::ControllerGL(model, view);

HWND hChild = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_MDICHILD,
                        g_szMDIChild_ClassName,
                        g_szMDIChild_Title,
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        rcClient.right,
                        rcClient.bottom,
                        g_hMDIClient,
                        NULL,
                        g_hInst,
                        (LPVOID)glCtrl);
If (!hWnd)
{
    delete model; model = NULL;
    delete view; view = NULL;
    delete glCtrl; glCtrl= NULL;
}
```

Many thanks to Remy Lebeau for his comments and answer, and if anyone else has a different/better method of doing this, please let me know.